# Angular 5 - Lodash differenceWith Not Working

Tags: angular, lodash

I am having an issue trying to get Lodash's differenceWith. I installed both the package and the **typings** in my Angular (5.2.6).

```
import { isEqual, differenceWith } from 'lodash/fp';

const diff = differenceWith([1,2,3], [1,2], isEqual);
```

However, I am getting an error with the simple statement. I am getting this build error:

> ERROR in src/app/user-management/add-user-roles/add-user-roles.component.ts(105,35): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable
>    to parameter of type 'Comparator2'.
>     Type 'number[]' provides no match for the signature '(a: number, b: {}): boolean'.

I don't think I am understanding error, because the comparator **isEqual** works fine!

```
const nothingNew = isEqual([1,2,3], [1,2]);
```

How do I get **differenceWith** to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your import to `import { isEqual, differenceWith } from 'lodash'`